# “Time-limited” vs “time-restricted” vs “temporary”

Tags: word-choice

I'm writing a spec about network authorization token mechanism where tokens are like usernames, but valid in some (narrow) time span only. For example, one may issue a token which can be used starting from `2018-04-09T00:00UTC` till `2018-04-11T00:00UTC`. Which wording suits this situation the best?

- time-limited authorization token
- time-restricted authorization token
- temporary authorization token

Comment: From an English point of view, all are acceptable.  As with all questions specific to a particular domain (Computer Science/Networking in this case), convention is king.  So, see what other people do.

Comment: Time-limited. English doesn't distinguish, but domain usage does. Temporary is used for password resets that force a new password. Time-restricted may refer to a time of day, such as "restricted to business hours". "Time-limited" means for a limited time period, such as the two days you indicate.

Comment: Please, firegurafiku, does your programming use a language wholly compliant with English, or not?

If it's wholly compliant, could you drop all reference to anything else?

If it's not, could you take the Question somewhere geared to that language?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: the question is about writing a technical specification which is not a program, but a text. It's not specific to any programming language.

Comment: @jimm101: if you find some time to convert your comment into an answer, I would glad to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Done, with a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Time-limited**, from *[time limit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time_limit)*:

> A limit of time within which something must be done.

[Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/time_limit)

English doesn't explicitly distinguish between these, but domain usage does. Temporary is commonly used for password resets that force a new password. *Time-restricted* may refer to a time of day, such as *restricted to business hours*. The definition of *time-limited* naturally encompasses the 48 hour period from the example.

Answer (score 1):

Temporal, as in a temporal cache.
This word has an existing similar usage in software engineering,  so likely to appeal to readers.